# Proper pattern for an action/tab bar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the correct pattern/structure for a set of 4 screens that have a tab bar at the bottom? I've just started out with Android. I believe this component is called an `Action Bar`.

Should it have 4 separate activities, each with the action bar XML code copied into each one (seems to violate dry principles)? Or is one activity, with each of the 4 tabs being a fragment, better?

My intuition is telling me that there is a better solution than either of these that is not occurring to me because I am so green.

Any suggestions?

[image: Example of the design I want to have]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView` to achieve this behavior and you just need only one `Activity` with Four `Fragmemt's`.

See [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html)

See [Design Guideline](https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-behavior)

**Here are some tutorials:**

1. [Android Bottom Navigation Bar Example](http://www.truiton.com/2017/01/android-bottom-navigation-bar-example/)
2. [Exploring the Android Design Support Library: Bottom Navigation View](https://medium.com/@hitherejoe/exploring-the-android-design-support-library-bottom-navigation-drawer-548de699e8e0)

Hope this will help~